# Web Push. fetching web pushes sent while offline?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am coding a vue.js app using web pushes with Firebase Cloud Messaging and I wondered if it was possible to send a web push to a user and in case the user was offline, to somehow store it for later display when the user opens the app again. Is there a principled approach to this problem, i.e. managing web pushes when the end user is offline?

The reason I am asking this is that, so far, all the web push notifications I've committed to FCM server with tokens of offline clients (i.e. desktop browsers) went into oblivion. To be sure, FCM didn't try pushing the notification again when the clients went back online.

For this reason I am considering coding a self-made dispatcher to manage web push for offline clients, but I need to make sure my efforts are worth it.

**updated**: I am now able to display notifications sent to an offline client after coming back online using appropriate `time_to_live` values. However, only the latest notification is displayed. How is there any specific reason why?

Answer (score 0):

FCM's default behavior is exactly like that. From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime):

> If the device is not connected to FCM, the message is stored until a connection is established (again respecting the collapse key rules). When a connection is established, FCM delivers all pending messages to the device.

Comment: Then that is not the behaviour I was able to witness. I used my web browser X to command FCM Server via the web app I am developping to send a push notification to my web browser Y, with Y's service worker and token appropriately set up and up-to-date, but the web browser closed. However no message went through when I opened it. However, all notifications are received when web browser Y is opened, either via some foreground or background listener. Is there a more rigorous procedure I could use to make sure my browser receives notifications when opening again my web app?

Comment: Can you make sure the passage you quote does apply to WEB pushes, as opposed to pushes to iOS and Android? If so can you correct you reply accordingly?

Comment: The passage is placed in the general location of the documentation -- which usually covers FCM behavior itself regardless of the client platform. Providing a complete answer to your post is just *too broad*. I would suggest editing your post to provide samples on what you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post above (apparently the `time_to_live` parameter was required to get the behaviour I wanted.). But see above for another -- possibly last problem...